# Is it possible to run spark yarn cluster from the code?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have a MapReduce task which I want to run on Spark YARN cluster from my java code. Also I want to retrieve reduce result (string and number pair, tuple) in my java code. Something like:

```
// I know, it's wrong setMaster("YARN"), but just to describe what I want.
// I want to execute job ob the cluster.
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test").setMaster("YARN");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

JavaRDD<Integer> input = sc.parallelize(list);

// map
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> results = input.mapToPair(new MapToPairExample());

// reduce
String max = results.max(new MyResultsComparator())._1();
```

It works if I set master to local, local[] or spark://master:7707.

So the question is: can I do the same with yarn cluster somehow?

Comment: `.setMaster("yarn-cluster") #or yarn-client `
`./spark-submit --master yarn-cluster`

You can check your status at `master:8088` and then click on `Application master` of running applications.

Answer (score 6):

Typically, a spark-submit command works the following way when passing the *master* as **yarn** and *deploy mode* as **cluster** (source: [Github code base for spark](https://github.com/apache/spark)):

1. *spark-submit* script calls *Main.java*
2. *Main.java* calls *SparkSubmit.java*
3. *SparkSubmit.java* calls *YarnClusterApplication* by figuring out the *master* and *deploy* parameters
4. *YarnClusterApplication* calls *Client.java*
5. *Client.java* talks to *Resource Manager* and hands over the *ApplicationMaster*.
6. The *Resource Manager* instantiates *ApplicationMaster.java* in a container on a Node Manager.
7. *ApplicationMaster.java*:

   1. allocates containers for *executors* using *ExecutorRunnables*
   2. uses reflection API to figure out the *main* method in the user supplied jar
   3. spawns a thread that executes the user application by invoking that *main* method from *Step 6.2*. This is where **your** code executes

In this flow, Steps 1-5 happen on the client/gateway machine. Starting from Step 6, everything executes on the Yarn cluster.

Now, to answer your question, I haven't ever tried executing spark in *yarn-cluster* mode from the code, but based on the above flow, **your** piece of code can only run within an application master container in a Node Manager machine of the Yarn cluster if you wish it to run in yarn-cluster mode. And, your code can reach there only if you specify *spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster* from the command line. So specifying it in the code and:

1. running the job e.g. from IDE will fail.
2. running the job using *spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster* will mean executing **your** code in a thread in the ApplicationMaster which runs on a Node Manager machine in the Yarn cluster and which will ultimately re-execute your *setMaster("yarn-cluster")* line of code which is now redundant but the rest of your code will run successfully.

Any corrections to this are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it using spark-submit. Spark submit handles many things for you from shipping dependencies to cluster and setting correct classpaths etc.
When you are running it as main java program in local mode your IDE is taking care of the classpath(since driver/executors are running in same jvm).

You can also use `"yarn-client"` mode if you want your driver program to run on your machine.

For yarn-cluster mode use `.setMaster("yarn-cluster")`

Answer (score 0):

would like to point you to some relevant classes that can help you do a spark submit from your code to yarn.

basically you can create a yarn deploy client : from the org.apache.spark:spark-yarn library.
there is a package called : org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn
which has a Client class.

the tricky part is that you should pass a sparkConf to that class and the spark conf should have your hadoopConf (of the cluster you try to deploy to)

for example you can try something like this (scala):

```html
 def rawHadoopConf(cluster: String): Configuration = {
    val hadoopConfig = new Configuration(false)
    hadoopConfig.addResource(new URL(s"http://hadoop-$cluster.com:50070/conf").openStream())
    hadoopConfig.set("fs.defaultFS", s"hdfs://$cluster/")
    hadoopConfig
  }
```

next you can do client.submitApplication()

Answer (score 0):

I ran a Spark job using the sparkConf.setMaster("yarn-cluster") from within the application (NOT via spark-submit) and it ran as expected. The driver spin up on one of the Hadoop node and several other executors as specified.
But if you want to initiate Spark job from within another Application you may try passing SparkConf and HadoopConf as explained above.